# Liver Disease prediction using SVM Deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, svm, prediction

I am working on a software that uses SVM model to predict if a person has liver disease or not.
i have the dataset of patients and non patients.
i want to train the model with this data and check wheather a new patient has disease. i am confused about getting user input. is it possible ?

Comment: are you want to get the new patient details as input from the user??

Comment: at first sight I would say yes. How many patient features do you have?

Comment: Just to make it clear. A simple binary classification with SVM is not part of deep learning. It is a (mostly) linear algorithm that is able to predict categories. The mathematical background is really not that advanced compared to real deep learning approaches  :)

Comment: i have about 400 patients record

Comment: yes i need to get new patient input from the user